# Can the enthalpy change of allotrope transformation can be done with Hess cycle?

Tags: physical-chemistry, enthalpy

My A- level textbook has some points about the uses of Hess cycle. For example: indirectly determining the lattice enthalpy, vaporisation enthalpy etc.

But, my book also says it is possible to determine the enthalpy change of allotrope transformation (eg. graphite to diamond); which I find hard to understand how. I have understood (and drawn the cycle) how to use Hess cycle for calculating lattice enthalpy and heat of vaporisation. But don't know how to do it for allotrope transformation. Is it really possible?

Comment: Explain you downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Can I direct you to Jim Clark's excellent book on A level calculations where the example you mention is covered?

If I remember correctly using combustion data for both allotropes allows the Hess cycle to be triangulated and the enthalpy of transformation from one to the other form to be calculated.

Comment: It would help if you be more elaborate on how the calculations are done, so people won't have to go to see the book. External references should be the additive, not the gist of your answer.

Comment: It will be better if you just shoe all of us the method here and do mention the link.

Comment: When would you mention the link? @Jim_Pearce